# Salesforce communities and custom object limitation

Tags: community

As per the documentation [here](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=users_license_types_communities.htm&language=en_US) it seems that for each community licence we have 10 custom object limit per license(custom objects used for managed packages are not included in this limit). 
Now in our org we have 200 partner community licence and 20000 customer community login licenses. Taking this into account any idea whether we need to keep this limit of custom objects in mind.

Any ideas or suggestions welcome, as we are planning for a solution for our customers in near future.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

According to the document you've linked to, the limit is 10 custom objects *per license*. I can only ask what kind of solution are you planning that would need a lot of custom objects per user?

With 200 partner licenses, you already have 2000 custom objects available to you. The 20000 customer community licenses would theoretically give you an additional 200,000 custom objects, which I believe would put you beyond the platform limits for an Enterprise Edition.

It would seem to me that you'll have more than enough custom objects available to do anything you could possibly want to do!

**Edit**

One thing I'll add is that custom objects would typically only be considered a community custom object if a community user directly interacted with it. Anything used as a "helper object" in the background, normally would not unless it showed up on a related list. As with all things Salesforce, I'd verify everything with your Account Representative.

Comment: Are you sure of this interpretation ? I've always understood that partner or community licenses only have access to 10 custom objects contractually. I've been told it's not a hard technical limit but may be detected by audits.

Comment: It would depend on whether Salesforce considers that portion a user based license or a "type of community" based-license (they don't say or speak in absolutes in that link, but do speak in the majority of it in terms of user based licenses). I'd interpret it as user based, but Salesforce can be very obtuse with their licensing structure & many things can depend on who you are & how much you spend with them. In his case, he has two community licenses and would seem to have at least 20 regardless if you look at it on a per community license basis.

Answer (score 2):

I was also not quite sure how to interpret this when I read about the limitation.I have since reached out to an AE (and a solution engineer) who has confirmed the following:

> Each community user can access up to 10 custom objects granted via
>   their profile.  However, you can have multiple user profiles accessing
>   the same community, each accessing 10 different custom objects, e.g.
>   profile 1 gets objects 1-10, profile 2 gets objects 11-20.
>
> More objects can be added so that an individual user/profile can
>   access above the 10 limit.  If we're talking significantly over that
>   10 limit, there's another license that would work called Lightning
>   External Apps Plus(its the furthest most right type on the second
>   link).  That one goes up to 200 per user/profile.

Hope this answers this question!