# Can I give CRUD permissions to custom object in Customer community

Tags: apex, trigger, permissions, customer-community, crud

I have salesforce Org which is using an app from the app-exchange, the objects in the app cant be given acces trough a Customer community. Is it possible to create a custom object i.e. PersonAccountComm__c and give this object the Create (CRUD) rights in the customer community and use a trigger to create standard Person-accounts. I know this isn't "best practises Salesforce" but from a financial standpoint this could be a solution. Hope someone has experience with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes**, you can give Community users create access to a custom object you create. [Keep in mind there are limitations to how many objects you may expose to these users.](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/115221/salesforce-communities-and-custom-object-limitation)